# Parse Cloud Code Promises in a for loop

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

As the title states, I'm having trouble with Promises in Parse.

I'm struggling to firstly understand exactly how Promises themselves work, especially in Parse.

I have been stuck on this for about three weeks and the closest I've come to a solution is having an empty array returned.

What I'm trying to do is scrape a site and then create objects from the table (this is working)

Where there trouble comes in, is I am then running a for loop on the results and querying each Dam name to get the resulting objectid from the database.

Here is my code:

```
var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections: 10,
    // This will be called for each crawled page
    callback: function(err, res, done) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            var $ = res.$;
            // $ is Cheerio by default
            //a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server
            console.log($("title").text());
        }
        done();
    }
});
```

The Function which Creates objects from the Dom and adds them to an array:

```
function getDamObjects(Dom) {
    var dom = Dom;
    var LevelObjects = [];

    for (i = 1; i < dom.length - 1; i++) {
        var TableRow = dom.eq(i);

        var NameString = TableRow.children().eq(0).text();
        var RiverString = TableRow.children().eq(1).text();
        var FSCString = TableRow.children().eq(4).text();
        var ThisWeekString = TableRow.children().eq(5).text();
        var LastWeekString = TableRow.children().eq(6).text();
        var LastYearString = TableRow.children().eq(7).text();

        NameString = NameString.replace('#', '');
        NameString = NameString.replace('$', '');
        NameString = NameString.replace('&', '');
        NameString = NameString.replace('@', '');

        ThisWeekString = ThisWeekString.replace('#', '');
        ThisWeekString = ThisWeekString.replace('$', '');
        ThisWeekString = ThisWeekString.replace('&', '');
        ThisWeekString = ThisWeekString.replace('@', '');

        LastWeekString = LastWeekString.replace('#', '');
        LastWeekString = LastWeekString.replace('$', '');
        LastWeekString = LastWeekString.replace('&', '');
        LastWeekString = LastWeekString.replace('@', '');

        LastYearString = LastYearString.replace('#', '');
        LastYearString = LastYearString.replace('$', '');
        LastYearString = LastYearString.replace('&', '');
        LastYearString = LastYearString.replace('@', '');

        var level = {};
        /*
        getDamObject(NameString).then(function(DamObject){
        let DamID = DamObject.id;
        */
        level['Dam'] = NameString; //DamID;
        level['ThisWeek'] = ThisWeekString;
        level['LastWeek'] = LastWeekString;
        level['LastYear'] = LastYearString;

        LevelObjects.push(level);
    };
    return LevelObjects;
};
```

The Get Dam Object Code:

```
function getDamObject(Dam) {
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    var query = new Parse.Query("DayZeroDams");
    query.equalTo("Name", Dam);
    query.first().then(function(DamObject) {
        promise.resolve(DamObject);
    }, function(error) {
        promise.reject(error);
    });

    return promise;
}
```

The Cloud Code Called:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('jsdom', function(request, response) {
    c.queue([{
        uri: 'xxxxxx',
        // The global callback won't be called
        callback: function(err, res, done) {
            if (err) {
                response.error(err);
            } else {
                var $ = res.$;
                var ResultsArray = [];
                var dom = res.$('#mainContent_tw').children('tr');
                return Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {
                    var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
                    var LevelObjects = getDamObjects(dom);
                    _.each(LevelObjects, function(DamLevel) {
                        promise = promise.then(function() {
                            var Name = DamLevel["Dam"];
                            var query = new Parse.Query("DayZeroDams");
                            query.equalTo("Name", Name);
                            return query.first().then(function(result) {
                                let damID = result.id;
                                ResultsArray.push(damID);
                                return Parse.Promise.as();
                            }, function(error) {
                                response.error(error);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    return promise;
                }).then(function() {
                    response.success(ResultsArray);
                }, function(error) {
                    response.error(error);
                });
                //response.success(LevelObjects);
            }
            done();
        }
    }]);
});
```

Please take note that I am fairly novice when it comes to Javascript, I have only recently started learning it in order to work with my server code.

Comment: Consider using indentation while typing code, it'll make things easier for you and for anyone else who has to read it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry about that ^^ I'm new here and I wasn't sure how to format my code properly since all my indentation changed when I pasted it here so I just followed the four spaces rule.

Comment: In short, make `getDamObjects` an `async` function, make each asynchronous call into a promise, and `await` each of them. Or, if waiting in serial is not what you want, use `await Promise.all` instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I want it in serial (I think I do at least). Would you be able to post a solution or at least an example which could point me in the right direction :)

Comment: @CertainPerformance PS is there any reason why you commented out the cloud code function? If it's badly written I'm sorry

Comment: @CertainPerformance And thank you so much for taking the time to reply, I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: I miscopied from the formatter, sorry about that

Comment: The `getDamObject` function isn't in the code you posted, but it looks to be the most important part - it looks like it returns a Promise that resolves to the value you want in `level.Dam`, is that correct, or not? Where do you want the DamObject to go?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh okay :) What do you suggest that I do with my functions because I didn't really understand what you meant by "await Promise.all" .... and on a side note, what formatter did you use? (so I can use it for future questions)

Comment: I just pasted the code into JSFiddle, `Tidy`d, indented twice ( => 4 spaces), and pasted it back into your post

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added the missing code, and thanks for the tip (regarding JSfiddle).

Comment: Where do you want the `DamObject` to go in your big `getDamObjects` loop?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Well I want the resulting objectID to be the level["Dam"] but I had received so many errors that I had to comment/remove the code while I tried to get the promises to work.

Basically the NameString I want to send to the getDamObject and and then put the returned Object in level["Dam"]

Comment: wow ... there's a lot of `Parse.Promise.as()` going on in there - I don't think you know how promises work to be honest

Comment: @JaromandaX I really don't, I have just read a lot of answers on here saying that they're the solution to other similar questions. I'm very noob.

Comment: getDamObject, getDamObjects and "Cloud Code Called" can be simpified to the code in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3a00sou/1/) - note: no use of async/await, and still uses Parse.Promise rather than native Promises

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks so much, will give it a look and reply here :)

Comment: Really, the async/await code is probably, these days, the better approach - just wanted to point out that it's not the only option, otherwise I'd have posted an answer rather than a link to a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `getDamObjects` into an async function and then `await` the result of each row, pushing it to the array:

```
function replaceSymbols(input) {
  return input.replace(/[#\$&@]/g, '');
}
async function getDamObjects(Dom) {
  const dom = Dom;
  const levelObjects = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < dom.length - 1; i++) {
    const children = dom.eq(i).children();

    const NameString = replaceSymbols(children.eq(0).text());
    const RiverString = children.eq(1).text();
    const FSCString = children.eq(4).text();
    const ThisWeek = replaceSymbols(children.eq(5).text());
    const LastWeek = replaceSymbols(children.eq(6).text());
    const LastYear = replaceSymbols(children.eq(7).text());

    const Dam = await getDamObject(NameString);
    levelObjects.push({
      Dam,
      ThisWeek,
      LastWeek,
      LastYear,
    });
  }
  return levelObjects;
}
```

Remember that now that getDamObjects is an async function, it will return a Promise that resolves to the array once iterations are complete. Consume it using `await getDamObjects` in another async function (or use `.then`)

Comment: So if I replace my getDamObjects with the code above, should I refer to it the same way that I have did previously? Will my code wait for the levelObjects if I leave the rest of it as it was?

Comment: Thank you for answering btw

Comment: @BLE No, like I said, you need to consume it using `await getDamObjects` or `.then`, because it returns a promise.

Comment: Sorry for being such a noob, I don't really understand the await function, do I just put it before getDamObjects when I refer to it in the cloud code?

Comment: and in the replace symbols function, must the 'g' be there in the symbols params?

Comment: `await` is not a function, it is a keyword that simplifies the readability of promises. The `/g` is the global regex flag to ensure that *all* instances get replaced, not just one.

Comment: oh I see, I added it into my code but I'm still getting the error "Error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."

Comment: I also see that you tend to use "const" over "let", why is that?

Comment: You are the best. I managed to get it to work using .then !! Thank you so much!! :D Seriously, I have been stuck on this for little more than a month and I've so relieved!!

Comment: I have another question, very similar to this one, I'm thinking that it'll be a lot easier to solve though. How would I then setup the above code as a job and have it fire every 3 hours indefinitely for example? PS I will mark this answer as correct

Comment: `const` should always be used over `let` when possible because it makes the code easier to read - if a `const` is declared on line 5, you know exactly what it's going to be on line 50 without reading lines 6-49.

Comment: If you're calling it in Javascript, setInterval maybe?

Comment: Ye it's in Javascript, okay I'll give it a look. Should I comment on this thread once I've given it a go?

Comment: No, it's a completely separate question, and you can probably just look up the docs anyway

Comment: Okay, cool well thank you regardless for your time. You have no idea how much of a help you've been!